# Get detailed error message when BGSAVE fails

Tags: redis

**Context**

We have a backup script which backs up several redis-server instances.

We chose the following way to backup a redis-server instance :

- start a `BGSAVE`
- regularly poll `INFO Persistence` (and `rdb_bgsave_in_progress`) to see if `BGSAVE` has completed
- check `rdb_last_bgsave_status` to see if all has gone well

Yesterday, something went wrong (the disk was full).
This error was adequately reported in redis logs, so with a human intervention, we were able to quickly find the cause.

Looking at the redis api however, I only see the generic  :

```
# Persitence
...
rdb_last_bgsave_status:err
```

line which indicates a generic kind of error, and I do not see how the automated script can report a more detailed error.

**Question**

When a `BGSAVE` has gone wrong, is there a way to access some kind of error code or error description through the redis api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - if the error is detailed, it will be in the logs. The Redis API doesn't feature an error log, although that could be a nice to have feature.